# Docker Desktop for windows + WSL2 (ubuntu) ( on Win10 PRO) problems with proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

I'm trying to connect docker with my corporate proxy. Tried many and many things across the internet, and nothing works.
I'm running docker on windows 10 pro edition and a ubuntu 20.04 lts on WSL2. The manual configuration on docker desktop seems to be not effective at all, it does nothing!
Running the simple image
`Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Proxy Authentication Required. See 'docker run --help'.`
I really tried everything i could find on internet, literally! Please help!

i treid to change every config file on several tutorials out there, but no sucess